# Use monoids to compute a frequency map of words

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am learning the book *functional programming in scala*. chapter 10, exercise 20, to implement the following method:

```
def frequencyMap(strings: IndexedSeq[String]): Map[String, Int]
```

honestly, I don't have a solution, so, I checked the answer from GIT:

```
 def mapMergeMonoid[K, V](V: Monoid[V]): Monoid[Map[K, V]] =
new Monoid[Map[K, V]] {
  def zero = Map()
  def op(a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V]) =
    a.map {
      case (k, v) => (k, V.op(v, b.get(k) getOrElse V.zero))
    }
}

 def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] =
   foldMapV(as, mapMergeMonoid[A, Int](intAddition))((a: A) => Map(a -> 1))
 def frequencyMap(strings: IndexedSeq[String]): Map[String, Int] = bag(strings)
```

But, when I tried to run a test, I got wrong answer:

```
frequencyMap(Vector("a rose", "is a", "rose is", "a rose"))
```

the answer printed:

```
Map(a rose -> 1)
```

the expected result:

```
Map(a -> 3, rose -> 3, is -> 2)
```

I can't figure out where is wrong with the implementation. could someone explain it for me? thanks.

**Edit after the correct answer, and update with a correct implementation**

```
 def mapMergeMonoid[K, V](V: Monoid[V]): Monoid[Map[K, V]] =
new Monoid[Map[K, V]] {
  def zero = Map()
  def op(a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V]) = {
    //        (a.map {
    //          case (k, v) => (k, V.op(v, b.get(k) getOrElse V.zero))
    //
    val c = for {
      (ka, va) <- a
      (kb, vb) <- b
      if (ka == kb)
    } yield (ka -> V.op(va, vb))

    a ++ b ++ c
  }
}

def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] =
    foldMapV(as, mapMergeMonoid[A, Int](intAddition))((a: A) => Map(a -> 1))
def frequencyMap(strings: IndexedSeq[String]): Map[String, Int] = bag(strings.map(_.split("\\s+")).flatten)
```

Comment: Problem is, you've confused words and phrases. When you pass in an `IndexedSeq[String]`, it's usually a collection of words, not phrases like you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the book, but following the code from [here](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/monoids/Monoid.scala), I can point out a few things for you to think about( based on some println()s in a REPL session ):

- As S.R.I pointed out, you have a list of phrases, not words.  The functions on github don't do anything to separate the word groups for you, so at best, your current input Vector could get:

  ```
  Map(a rose -> 2, is a -> 1, rose is -> 1)
  ```

  You could create a list of words by doing the following to your Vector:

  ```
  Vector("a rose", "is a", "rose is", "a rose") map( _.split( " " ).toSeq ) flatten
  ```
- The `mapMergeMonoid` function only appears to add the value of k and v together when there keys(k) are the same.  Meaning an unsorted list is going to result in a lot of `Map(string -> 1)`.

  You could sort the Vector of words by making the following changes to Vector:

  ```
  (Vector("a rose", "is a", "rose is", "a rose") map( _.split( " " ).toSeq ) flatten) sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0)
  ```
- While `foldMapV` does split out all the phrases or words from the Vector in a `Map[String, Int]`, it only appears to return the leftmost desired merge for a sorted IndexedSeq.  With a sorted Vector of words as I've indicated, I got the result `Map(a -> 3)` from your implementation of `frequencyMap`.  I would be inclined to use something other than `foldMapV` though or modify it to make `frequencyMap` work.  The bit that appears to be missing to me is an accumulation of the results of the function it's applying into one large Map.  I would also try a more "standard" head/tail recursion than the splitAt() calls(as I'm not convinced the `foldMapV` was handling `is` and `rose` very well).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer inspired me, that I make it correct now.